# R character strings are limited to 2^31-1 bytes

Tags: r

I am  working  with `neo4r`  library in R. When i use this function

```
call_neo4j(con, type = "graph")
```

I get the error

```
Fehler in readBin(content, character()) :  R character strings are limited to 2^31-1 bytes
```

Anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: It looks like your input data to the `neo4r` library is more than 2GB.  But, you have an even bigger problem here, because if a single variable require _more_ than 2GB, then it is quite likely that your entire script would exceed the memory available to R.

Comment: could we have a little more context please?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: R can handle data frames and data.tables of over 80GB without problem. The problem here lies in the fact that OP reached a limit on individual objects. From the documentation: "The number of bytes in a character string is limited to 2^31 - 1 ~ 2*10^9, which is also the limit on each dimension of an array."

Comment: @SamuelDiebolt Sure...and the OP will never get anywhere near that limit, because R runs in memory and it is doubtful that the OP has that much available RAM.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think it's safe to assume OP has at least 2GB of available RAM, otherwise running any kind of application using Neo4J is pretty much out of the question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As the error would suggest, you reached the limit on the size of character strings. From [the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html):

> The number of bytes in a character string is limited to 2^31 - 1 ~ 2*10^9, which is also the limit on each dimension of an array.

Without more information, we can't help you solve this problem. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2414988) to create a minimal reproducible example that could help us solve your problem.